# Create new invoice with the remaining amount of money after partial refund (Credit Memo)

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, invoice

Alright i have the following problem:

We use Magento 1.4.1.1 and looking for the way to add the following functionality:

After a partial refund has been made with Credit Memo, we need to automatically create a new invoice for this order with the remaining amount of money, is this possible ?

Currently it looks to me that to add this functionality we will have to override the existing module that creates Credit Memo and try to track down the remaining amount of money and the remaining items to be able to create a new invoice.

Should it actually be right to create the new invoice for the same order ? I mean that we will have to put an additional code at the point when Credit Memo for partial refund is created, that performs the following:

1. Tracks down all the needed information (amount of money, remaining items etc)
2. Creates new invoice for this order using this data.

Also currently there is a canInvoice() parameter for order and as far as i know it won\’t let you create another invoice if there already is one, so we will have to somehow override this also ?

Or probably we will have to create a new order with the remaining items and then create an invoice for it ?